# How to parse numbers data from EDID

Tags: c++, parsing, string-parsing, edid

I have a way of obtaining the EDID info of monitors with nVidia API, this gives me an array of 128 unsigned chars. When reading up on the edid data format on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) however I noticed that the letters in the manufacturer id (bytes 8-9) are represented as 5 bit numbers, so I don't know how I go about reading that into C++ as meaningful data.

My plan was to just define a struct type which matched the format of the edid and cast my char array to that struct type, but I don't know if that's possible now since the smallest sized data types I know of in C++ are one byte in size.

Thanks.

Bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to extract and manipulate information which is less than one byte, you need to use [bit-wise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

For example, in order to extract a 5-bit number stored as the first (least-significant) 5-bits of a `char`, you could say:

```
unsigned char x = (BYTE & 0x1F);
```

Which will store the value represented by the right 5 bits of `BYTE` in `x`.  In that example, I used an AND operator (the `&` operator in C/C++), which basically uses a mask to hide the 3 most-significant (left-most) bits of the value, (using the hex value 1F, which is `00011111` in binary) isolating the initial 5 bits.

Other bitwise operators include OR, XOR, and left/right bit-shifting, which are performed in C++ using the `|`, `^`, `<<` and `>>` operators respectively.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I have another question though. The data is stored in a char array, so I will need some kind of offset from which to read the data, the first number is bits 0-4, the second bit is bits 5-9...so that will be the last 3 bits of the first byte and the first bit of the second byte, etc. I don't know how I would start reading from some offset from a char

Comment: The same way you would address an offset in a char array normally, using the `[]` operator.  If you wanted to perform a bit operation to extract 5 bits of the 2nd byte, for example, you could say `array[1] & 0x1F`

Answer (score 0):

Use bit manipulation (i.e. shifting) to extract the bits of each character and use a lookup table (for better portability) to convert them into characters.

```
uint16_t EDID_vendor_ID = EDID[8] | EDID[9] << 8;
char char_LUT[]={' ', 'A', 'B', /*...*/ 'Z'};
char ID[3] = { char_LUT[ (EDID_vendor_ID >> 6) & 7 ], 
               char_LUT[ (EDID_vendor_ID >> 3) & 7 ],
               char_LUT[ (EDID_vendor_ID     ) & 7 ] }
```